# Get an array after filtering the data from the given values in javascript react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am new to react. Here I have an object which has array (Map)

```
"POSSIBLE_UPDATE_OPTIONS": {
        "Process": ["confirm"],
        "Confirmed": [
          "Process",
          "Validated"
        ],
        "Validated": [
          "Process",
          "Sent"
        ],
        "Sent": []
      }
```

Now, Here current status value is process. Now, if it is process it should return the ['confirm'] array. these are the possible option for this change.

Now, I have written one function for this .

```
const validate = (currentstatus) => {
  let possibleOptions =
          config?.appConfig?.?.POSSIBLE_UPDATE_OPTIONS_MAP?.[
            data
          ] ?? []
   return possibleoptions
}
```

This will return me the array .Now, I have to convert this array element into an object in the

lets say I have got the ["confirm"] as return .

Now, object would be like

```
[{
  "label": "confirm",
  "value": "VIP:confirm"
}]
```

SO, here need to add `VIP:` in the value key.

So, this function should return me an array of object in this format.

Can any one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function.

**Like this**

```js
const validate = (currentstatus) => {
    let possibleOptions =
            config?.appConfig?.?.POSSIBLE_UPDATE_OPTIONS_MAP?.[
              data
            ] ?? []
     return possibleoptions.map(item => ({label: `${item}`, value: `VIP:${item}`}))
  }
```

Comment: I do have a bit of doubt will my first code will retun the possobleOptions I mean first line by passing a string.